# What passes as true (or false) in an if statement for a variable

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, flex4.5

In this code, what values of `myVar` will behave as `true` and `false`?

```
if(myVar){}
```

In JavaScript for example, the following values are falsy

```
null
undefined
0
''
false
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Object**

> `false` if the instance is `null`; `true` otherwise

**String**

> `false` if the value is `null` or the empty string `""`; `true` otherwise

**Number, int, or uint**

> `false` if the value is `NaN` or `0`; `true` otherwise

**null**

> `false`

From [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/learn/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9c.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f87).

Answer (score 1):

If `(myVar)` is a bool, then it'll obvious pass if it's true, and fail if not. If the bool was never initialized (like `var myBool:Boolean;` instead of `var myBool:Boolean = true`) then it's false by default. This same concept applies to builtin objects like Number, int etc. Pretty much for everything else, it will only pass as true if the object has been initialized through the object constructor or through a direct assignment, like so:

```
var a:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

var b:MovieClip = a;
```

Comment: One minor correction to what I said about how this concept pretty much applies to all "builtin" objects, that even isn't necessarily true. Some objects like the Array object are null unless initialized as well. And as you've stated in your question it's pretty much the same, null and undefined will fail.